# Is there anyway i can get value from groovy closure

Tags: groovy, closures, jenkins-groovy

I have a closure as below and i want to get value from a, b, c.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
entry {
    a = false
    b = "nodejs"
    c = "xxx"
}
println entry.a
println entry.b
println entry.c
```

Is there any way i can achieve this ?
I always got the error as below

```
% groovy jenkinsfile.groovy
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: jenkinsfile.entry() is applicable for argument types: (jenkinsfile$_run_closure1) values: [jenkinsfile$_run_closure1@12aba8be]
Possible solutions: every(), every(groovy.lang.Closure), any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), notify(), identity(groovy.lang.Closure)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: jenkinsfile.entry() is applicable for argument types: (jenkinsfile$_run_closure1) values: [jenkinsfile$_run_closure1@12aba8be]
Possible solutions: every(), every(groovy.lang.Closure), any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), notify(), identity(groovy.lang.Closure)
    at jenkinsfile.run(jenkinsfile.groovy:2)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

**I have to use this way because I have lots of Jenkinsfile writing in this format and i want to get values from Jenkinsfile. That's format from Jenkinsfile.**

Comment: No then, it's not possible if you can't or won't change it

Comment: `entry {a=false ...}` is not a closure. it looks like a call to a function called `entry` which takes a parameter a closure body which is the block between { and }. Since there is no function `entry` defined, you get that error.

Answer (score 0):

how about you use a map literal for this:

```
entry = [
    a:false,
    b:"nodejs",
    c:"xxx"
]
println entry.a
println entry.b
println entry.c
```

Comment: I have to use this way because I have lots of Jenkinsfile writing in this format and i want to get values from Jenkinsfile. That's format from Jenkinsfile.

Comment: It might make sence to read those files as text and parse the values with some regex